# Using a Variable in a SQLite String Field

Tags: android, sqlite, variables

I have an application that has the following variable:

```
public static final String BUSINESS_NAME = "Blahr Industries";
```

however that String will change depending on who the application is customized for:
(so for example another app might be)

```
public static final string BUSINESS_NAME = "Blech LTD";
```

Now I also have a database that houses the same information for each version of the application.  When retrieved and subsequently displayed the application will need to put in the BUSINESS_NAME variable at the correct place:
(ie)

```
String contentText = "Yada yada, blah blah, promises promises at _____ and we will all be happy";
```

where " ***_*_**" = BUSINESS_NAME

** THE QUESTION **

Is there a way to put a variable marker (paramater?) in the String object that will be recognized by Android upon display and filled in? 
In other words, is it possible to insert the "contentText" String into a SQLite Database so that when it is returned and displayed it will show the correction Business name amidst the other text?

I've read a bit about SQL parameters but don't understand them properly.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried `String.replace()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put this in the database

```
String dbEntry = "Yada yada, blah blah, promises promises at %s and we will all be happy";
```

and when you retrieve it from the database, format the string like this

```
String contentText = String.format(dbEntry, BUSINESS_NAME);
```